# save the exec output into a file

Tags: php, shell

I'm running a shell command ( its a web **scraper** ) via php exec ( although, i have tried system and passthru as well) and i need to save the results in a file, (preferably .txt),The output data is some HTML.
it  creates the file, but its always empty.

please help me out.

Below is the code, im trying to run

```
file_put_contents('data.php',passthru('casperjs the_file_in_which_i_run.js',$output));
```

also tried

```
file_put_contents('data.php',exec('casperjs the_file_in_which_i_run.js',$output));
```

and

```
file_put_contents('data.php',system('casperjs the_file_in_which_i_run.js',$output));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
exec(...., $output);
file_put_contents('file.txt', $output);
```